# Spread Celery Django tasks out over 24 hours

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, django-celery

I have tasks that do a get request to an API.
I have around 70 000 requests that I need to do, and I want to spread them out in 24 hours. So not all 70k requests are run at for example 10AM.

How would I do that in celery django? I have been searching for hours but cant find a good simple solution.

The database has a list of games that needs to be refreshed. Currently I have a cron that creates tasks every hour. But is it better to create a task for every game and make it repeat every hour?

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach is to send them whenever you need some work done, no matter how many there are (even hundreds of thousands). The execution however is controlled by how many workers (and worker processes) you have subscribed to a dedicated queue. The key here is the dedicated queue - that is a common way of not allowing all workers start executing the newly created tasks. This goes beyond the basic Celery usage. You need to use `celery multi` for this use-case, or create two or more separate Celery workers manually with different queues.

If you do not want to over-complicate things you can use your current setup, but make these tasks with lowest priority, so if any new, more important, task gets created, it will be executed first. Problem with this approach is that only Redis and RabbitMQ backends support priorities as far as I know.